# How do you aggregate rows and pick the value for a specific date?

Tags: r, date, dplyr, aggregate

Yesterday I asked a question 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60914247/how-do-you-aggregate-rows-to-a-factor-variable-with-three-levels) about how to aggregate multiple rows into a factor with three levels. This is fixed! However, my supervisor also wants to make a second dataframe. I will explain my dataframe:

My data contains participants that have multiple rows. There are different variables types (e.g., age, date, factor variables etc.). I have aggregated the data so that each participant has one row with the following code

```
example4 <- SMARTdata_50j_diagc_2016  %>% 
  group_by( Patient_Id ) %>%  
  summarise( Groep = first( Groep ),
             Ziekenhuis_Nr = first( Ziekenhuis_Nr ),
             Ziekenhuistype = first( Ziekenhuistype ),
             aantalDBC = n(),
             aantalVervolg = sum( as.numeric( ifelse( Zorgtype_Code == 0, 0, 1 ) ) ),
             Diagnose_code = case_when( 
               all( Diagnose_Code == 1 ) ~ 1,
               all( Diagnose_Code == 0 ) ~ 0, 
               TRUE ~ 2 ),
             Leeftijd = mean( Lft_patient_openenDBC ),
             Geslacht = first( Geslacht ),
             MRI_nee_ja = max( ifelse( MRI_nee_ja == 0, 0, 1 ) ),
             aantalMRI = sum( MRI_Aantal ),
             Artroscopie_nee_ja = max( ifelse( Artroscopie_nee_jaz_jam == 0, 0, 1 ) ),
             aantalArtroscopie = sum( Artroscopie_aantal ),
             overigDBC = mean( Aantal_overigeDBC_bijopenen ),
             DBC_open = min( open_DBC ), 
             DBC_sluiten = max( sluiten_DBC ) ) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

This code is correct and works. As you can see, for 'Diagnose_code' there are three values present (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60914247/how-do-you-aggregate-rows-to-a-factor-variable-with-three-levels)). The participant that have a value 2 in this new dataframe have in reality both a value of 0 and 1 in the original dataframe. My supervisor wants to make a second dataframe where, instead of those participants getting a value of 2, they get the value that is linked to the latest date of open_DBC. Variable open_DBC is a 'yearmon' type.

I've been thinking about using the advice I got yesterday and work with case_when, something like

```
Diagnose_code = case_when( 
               all( Diagnose_Code == 1 ) ~ 1,
               all( Diagnose_Code == 0 ) ~ 0, 
               TRUE ~ Diagnose_Code[, max( open_DBC )] )
```

but this is not correct. I am not sure how I should pick the Diagnose_Code value that belongs to the max date of open_DBC. Does anyone know how to tackle this problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `which.max` :

```
Diagnose_code = case_when( 
       all( Diagnose_Code == 1 ) ~ 1,
       all(Diagnose_Code == 0 ) ~ 0, 
       TRUE ~ Diagnose_Code[which.max(open_DBC)])
```

Or :

```
 Diagnose_code = case_when( 
     all( Diagnose_Code == 1 ) ~ 1,
     all( Diagnose_Code == 0 ) ~ 0, 
    TRUE ~ Diagnose_Code[open_DBC == max(open_DBC)])
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this immediately!

Comment: My apologies, at first I got an error, but that was due to the type of my variable. I changed it and your advice worked, thank you very much!